# Extra property is returned when using jsonview in Spring mvc4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC(4.x) and I met a strange problem:

```
@RequestMapping("/xx")
class Controller{

    @RequestMapping(produce="application/json")
    public Resource list(@RequestParameter String key, @RequestParameter Page page){
        ArrayList list=.....
        return new Resource(list,page);
    }
}

class Page{
    int page;
    int size;
    ...
}

class Resource<T>{
  private List<T> list;
  private Page page;
  //getter and setter omitted
}
```

Once I call:

http://.../xx/?key=key&page=1&size=10

I will got the json result,however it looks something like this:

```
{
    page:...
    resource:{
        list:...
        page:...
    }
}
```

I wonder why the `page` property at the root is returned?

Comment: what is the resource class